# Knockout + MVC disable html button and change color after ajax call

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I want to toggle `disabled` property for button after ajax call is successful.
The button is doing an ajax call to backend, and if returns as success, I have to disable that specific button.

I **have n buttons**, because they are generated in foreach loop for a table rows.

```
...
<td>
    <button class="button primary" data-bind="click: $parent.sendDataToApi, attr: {'disabled' : passedIntegration }, style: { background: passedIntegration ? 'gray' : '' }">Send button</button>
</td>
...
```

My question is, am I need to put for each button id selector, or knockout somehow "knows" which button is ajax called, and only that button to disable and change color to gray?

my knockout.js file looks like:

```
define(['viewmodels/shell', 'durandal/services/logger', 'plugins/dialog', 'viewmodels/shell', 'toastr', 'knockout', 'kovalidationconfig', 'plugins/router', 'typeahead.bundle'],
    function (shell, logger, dialog, shell, toastr, ko, kvc, router, typeahead) {
        var vm = {
            activate: activate,
            shell: shell,
            data: ko.observableArray([]),
            close: function () {
                $(window).off('popstate', vm.goBack);
                $(window).off('resize', adjustModalPosition);
                dialog.close(vm, 'cancel');
            },
            goBack: function () {
                $(window).off('popstate', vm.goBack);
                $(window).off('resize', adjustModalPosition);
                dialog.close(vm, 'back');
            },
            editPreregisteredChildren: function () {
                router.navigate("#/function/" + this.id);
            },
            sendDataToApi: function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: rootUrl + 'home/sendData',
                    data: ko.toJSON({
                        requestId: this.id

                    }),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.success === true) {
                            toastr.success(data.message)
                            // set that specific button disabled, remove hand-cursor, change background color to gray
                        } else {
                            toastr.error(data.message);
                        }
                    }
                   
                });
            }
        };
);
```

As you can see, I done the GET part, where on loading the rows, I setup buttons disabled/enabled, though I didnt figure it yet how to remove hand cursor on disabled button?

I stuck with other part, when I do ajax call, if call was successfull I also need to disable button.
Any suggestions how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are a couple of ways to handle it. You didn't post which variable you are using in the forEach loop, but it will depend on that. I'm going to assume it's the "data" observableArray.

So if "data" is an array of objects, you can add an observable property to it, and then bind the disable to that property.

```
data = [{property: ..., disable: ko.observable()}]
```

Then you can pass in the array object you are on to the method by adding a parameter to the method as follows:

```
sendDataToApi: function (e) {
```

and change the binding to:

```
data-bind="click: $parent.sendDataToApi($data), disable: disable"
```

This will make "e" in the method the current iteration you are on, and then you can change set e.disable(true) when appropriate.